# Show the data into EST timezone from UTC timezone in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-carbon

My **created_at** and **updated_at** column is inserted in UTC timezone. Now I want to show the data according to "**america/chicago**" timezone. I am using the Carbon library to get the result.

Below is the code I have written to fetch the information from database.

```
    public function getAllUsers(){
        $users =  BaseUserModel::
        select('id', 'email', 'created_at')
            ->whereDate(
                'created_at',
                '=',
                Carbon::today('america/chicago')
            )
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->limit(5)->get();
        return $users;
    }
```

[image]

Attached database entry with UTC time. Now when I am trying to execute the query, getting only one output(**2018-10-03 15:27:18**). But my expected output should come both date in "america/timezone".

See the difference of UTC and America/Chicago timezone.
https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to query using UTC date/time. As an example, if you want 2018-10-03 0:00:00 CST to 2018-10-03 23:59:59 CST you need to query using 2018-10-03 6:00:00 to 2018-10-04 5:59:59 depending on timezone and day light savings time.